# Evidence that Graph Isomorphism problem is not $NP$-complete

Tags: computational-complexity, isomorphism-testing

Graph isomorphism problem is one of the longest standing problems that resisted classification into $P$ or $NP$-complete problems. We have evidences that it can not be $NP$-complete. Firstly, Graph Isomorphism can not be $NP$-complete unless the polynomial hierarchy [1] collapses to the second level. Also, the counting[2] version of GI is polynomial-time Turing equivalent to its decision version which does not hold for any known $NP$-complete problem. The counting version of *natural* $NP$-complete problems seems to have much higher complexity since they are $\#P$-complete. Finally, the lowness result [3] of GI with respect to $PP$ ($PP^{GI}=PP$) is not known to hold for any $NP$-complete problem. The lowness result of GI has been improved to $SPP^{GI}=SPP$ after Arvind and Kurur proved that GI is in $SPP$ [4].

**Edit**: It is known that SAT is truth-table equivalent to USAT (set of Boolean formulas with exactly one satisfying assignment) while it is not known whether GI and UGI are equivalent under polynomial time truth-table reductions.

> What other (recent) results can provide further evidence that GI can not be $NP$-complete?

[1]: Uwe Schöning, "Graph isomorphism is in the low hierarchy", Proceedings of the 4th Annual Symposium on Theoretical Aspects of Computer Science, 1987, 114–124

[2]: R. Mathon, "A note on the graph isomorphism counting problem", Information Processing Letters, 8 (1979) pp. 131–132

[3]: Köbler, Johannes; Schöning, Uwe; Torán, Jacobo (1992), "Graph isomorphism is low for PP", Computational Complexity 2 (4): 301–330

[4]: V. Arvind and P. Kurur. Graph isomorphism is in SPP, ECCC TR02-037, 2002.

Comment: The Hidden Subgroup Problem contains as a special case GI, but I don't believe it contains any problems known to be NP-complete: see, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem. Put another way, it is plausible that a quantum computer could efficiently solve GI, but few people think a quantum computer can efficiently solve an NP-complete problem.

Comment: Integer factorization has also resisted classification. Is graph isomorphism a "longer standing" problem than factorization?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think stating that GI is "longest standing" is not accurate. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: reposted (with proper reference to this question) at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29266/evidence-that-graph-isomorphism-problem-is-not-np-complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search done for a [related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-evidence-is-there-that-graph-isomorphism-is-not-in-p) also turned up (as indicated in a comment) [rjlipton.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/news-on-intermediate-problems](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/news-on-intermediate-problems/):

> Now Eric and Bireswar [complete](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2014/068/) the triad of relations to the other intermediate problems:
>
> > **Theorem 2** *Graph Isomorphism is in ${\mathsf{RP}^{\mathrm{MCSP}}}$. Moreover, every promise problem in ${\mathsf{SZK}}$ belongs to ${\mathsf{BPP}^{\mathrm{MCSP}}}$ as defined for promise problems.*

Here $\mathsf{RP}$ stands for [randomized polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP_(complexity)), MCSP is the Minimum Circuit Size Problem, and $\mathsf{SZK}$ stands for Statistical Zero Knowledge. So we learn that if MCSP is not NP-complete and RP!=NP, then graph isomorphism is not NP-complete either.